# how to understand the syntax of kineticjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, kineticjs, tween

This is the first time around that I am using some js,otherwise I always rely on hardcoding.Probably this is the reason why I am facing some issues in understanding the syntax of kineticjs.
I saw some

```
 1. Tween
 2. layer(add)
 3. stage(add)
 4. var rect=new kinetic.rect{//some code with property:value,}
```

I am familiar with *constructor and creating instances* of it.But I am finding it difficult to understand the syntax of kineticjs.What are the above things **used** for,i have no idea.I tried searching but I din`t get what I was looking for.
I have a project in which I need to increase the height of bezier curve with transition.Kineticjs seems to be the only solution for this.
So my question is how to define *my own custom function in kineticjs* and *how to call it* with respect to the kineticjs syntax?

[this is what I have done so far!!!](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshjain24/UmSss/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Tweens are used to animate a node from one state into another state.  For example, you can use Tweens to animate a rectangle from position x=10 to x=50
2. this adds a node to a layer.  You can add groups and shapes to layers
3. this adds a layer to the stage.  Layers are tied to an HTML5 canvas
4. this instantiates a new rectangle.  Here's the full documentation on rectangles: http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Rect.html

For more info, take a look at the "how it works page"

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki

Comment: :thx for the answer.i have understood how it works. But when it comes to instantiating,i am facing a problem!!!this is the link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002709/how-to-create-object-and-instance-in-kineticjs

Comment: :some random person in this universe comes up with a question,and look who replies..the creator itself..
thanks stackOverflow!!!!

Comment: :kinetic have inbuilt functionality for circle,rect when you want to do some animation.but what when if you want to some animation with bezier curve.This is the link for what I have done
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026783/how-to-add-movements-to-bezier-curve-in-kineticjs

Answer (score 1):

Try to watch this youtube video. Its a presentation from the founder of kineticjs. He talk about HTML5 graphics frameworks in generale in the start, but if you go to time 39:45, then he talks about exactly the things you are asking about. He is giving a live coding example which makes it very easy to understand. Check it out:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZS6QqNJ0VRA