# how to add movements to bezier curve in kineticjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs, layer, stage

I have done this without kinetic.This piece of code is working fab as I wanted.
[--fiddle without kineticjs. Take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshjain24/UmSss/)

Now I want to do the same code with kineticjs. Here is is what I have done till now[--fiddle with kineticjs](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshjain24/w8e6K/).

The lines don`t move at all?where am I going wrong?I have spent the entire day but couldnt figure out the problem.

This is my javascript with kinetic.results cannot be seen in fiddle because there is no option for including kineticjs.though I have put my code up there.Any help is welcome.

```
var stage=new Kinetic.Stage({
    container:'container',
    width:500,
    height:500
});

var layer=new Kinetic.Layer();

var bg=new Kinetic.Rect({
    x:0,
    y:0,
    width:stage.getWidth(),
    height:stage.getHeight(),
    fill: 'antiquewhite'
});
layer.add(bg);

var drawHair = function(canvas) {
    var context = canvas.getContext();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.attrs.sx, this.attrs.sy);
    context.bezierCurveTo(this.attrs.cp1x, this.attrs.cp1y, this.attrs.cp2x, this.attrs.cp2y, this.attrs.endx, this.attrs.endy);
    context.closePath();
    canvas.fillStroke(this);
};

function Hair(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) {
    return new Kinetic.Shape({
        drawFunc: drawHair,
        fill: '#000',
        lineJoin: 'round',
        stroke: 'grey',
        strokeWidth: 8,
        sx: 136 + a,//start position of curve.used in moveTo(sx,sy)
        sy: 235 + b,
        cp1x: 136 + c,//control point 1
        cp1y: 222 + d,
        cp2x: 136 + e,//control point 2
        cp2y: 222 + f,
        endx: 136 + g,//end points
        endy: 210 + h
    });
}

var hd =[];
function init(){//this function draws each hair/curve
        hd.push(new Hair(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
        layer.add(hd[0]);
        hd.push(new Hair(15, 0, 15, 0, 15, 0, 15, 0));
        layer.add(hd[1]);
        hd.push(new Hair(30, 0, 30, 0, 30, 0, 30, 0));
        layer.add(hd[2]);
        hd.push(new Hair(45, 0, 45, 0, 45, 0, 45, 0));
        layer.add(hd[3]);
        hd.push(new Hair(60, 0, 60, 0, 60, 0, 60, 0));
        layer.add(hd[4]);
        hd.push(new Hair(75, 0, 75, 0, 75, 0, 75, 0));
        layer.add(hd[5]);
        hd.push(new Hair(90, 0, 90, 0, 90, 0, 90, 0));
        layer.add(hd[6]);
        hd.push(new Hair(105, 0, 105, 0, 105, 0, 105, 0));
        layer.add(hd[7]);
        hd.push(new Hair(120, 0, 120, 0, 120, 0, 120, 0));
        layer.add(hd[8]);

    stage.add(layer);
}

    var bend1=0;
    var bend2=0;
    var bend3=0;
    var bend4=0;
    var bend5=0;
    var bend6=0;
    var bend7=0;
    var bend8=0;
    var bend9=0;

stage.on('mousemove', function() {
    var ref1=135;//this is ref point for  hair or curve no 1
    var ref2=150;//hair no 2 and so on
    var ref3=165;
    var ref4=180;
    var ref5=195;
    var ref6=210;
    var ref7=225;
    var ref8=240;
    var ref9=255;
    var pos = stage.getMousePosition();
    console.log("x="+pos.x+"&&"+"y="+pos.y)
    if(between(pos.x,115,270) && between(pos.y,205,236))
    {
        if(pos.x>=ref1 && pos.x<=145){bend1=(pos.x-ref1)*(2.2);}
        if(pos.x<=ref1 && pos.x>=125){bend1=(pos.x-ref1)*(2.2);}

        if(pos.x>=ref2 && pos.x<=160){bend2=(pos.x-ref2)*(2.2);}
        if(pos.x<=ref2 && pos.x>=140){bend2=(pos.x-ref2)*(2.2);}

        if(pos.x>=ref3 && pos.x<=175){bend3=(pos.x-ref3)*(2.2);}
        if(pos.x<=ref3 && pos.x>=155){bend3=(pos.x-ref3)*(2.2);}

        if(pos.x>=ref4 && pos.x<=190){bend4=(pos.x-ref4)*(2.2);}
        if(pos.x<=ref4 && pos.x>=170){bend4=(pos.x-ref4)*(2.2);}

        if(pos.x>=ref5 && pos.x<=205){bend5=(pos.x-ref5)*(2.2);}
        if(pos.x<=ref5 && pos.x>=185){bend5=(pos.x-ref5)*(2.2);}

        if(pos.x>=ref6 && pos.x<=220){bend6=(pos.x-ref6)*(2.2);}
        if(pos.x<=ref6 && pos.x>=200){bend6=(pos.x-ref6)*(2.2);}

        if(pos.x>=ref7 && pos.x<=235){bend7=(pos.x-ref7)*(2.2);}
        if(pos.x<=ref7 && pos.x>=215){bend7=(pos.x-ref7)*(2.2);}

        if(pos.x>=ref8 && pos.x<=250){bend8=(pos.x-ref8)*(2.2);}
        if(pos.x<=ref8 && pos.x>=230){bend8=(pos.x-ref8)*(2.2);}

        if(pos.x>=ref9 && pos.x<=265){bend9=(pos.x-ref9)*(2.2);}
        if(pos.x<=ref9 && pos.x>=245){bend9=(pos.x-ref9)*(2.2);}
    }
    hd.push(new Hair(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0+bend1, 0));
    layer.add(hd[0]);
    hd.push(new Hair(15, 0, 15, 0, 15, 0, 15+bend2, 0));
    layer.add(hd[1]);
    hd.push(new Hair(30, 0, 30, 0, 30, 0, 30+bend3, 0));
    layer.add(hd[2]);
    hd.push(new Hair(45, 0, 45, 0, 45, 0, 45+bend4, 0));
    layer.add(hd[3]);
    hd.push(new Hair(60, 0, 60, 0, 60, 0, 60+bend5, 0));
    layer.add(hd[4]);
    hd.push(new Hair(75, 0, 75, 0, 75, 0, 75+bend6, 0));
    layer.add(hd[5]);
    hd.push(new Hair(90, 0, 90, 0, 90, 0, 90+bend7, 0));
    layer.add(hd[6]);
    hd.push(new Hair(105, 0, 105, 0, 105, 0, 105+bend8, 0));
    layer.add(hd[7]);
    hd.push(new Hair(120, 0, 120, 0, 120, 0, 120+bend9, 0));
    layer.add(hd[8]);
    stage.add(layer);
    console.log("bend1="+bend1);

});

function between(val, min, max) {
    return val >= min && val <= max;
}

window.onload = function() {
    init();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem:

You are adding 9 additional Shape objects with every stage mousemove event.

That means you quickly create hundreds (thousands) of hairs.

Start with a redesign where you have only 9 hairs.

During mousemove events, you would respond by changing each hair's bend in their `drawFunc`.

**[ Edited to include example code ]**

You can create a “smart” hair that listens if the mouse is over it and bends itself accordingly.

Then you can add as many smart hairs as you need.

You don't need to track what they're doing, because each one contains enough info+code to bend itself properly.

Since this is just an instructional example, I’ve simplified your curves into a 2 part line which is vertical at the bottom and “bent” at the top.

[image]

Here’s the draw function for the custom hair shape.  The top of the line is “bent” towards the mouse position. If the mouse has moved inside the hairs response area, the hairs endX property will be set to the mouseX position.  This causes the hair to be bent towards the mouseX.

```
drawFunc: function(canvas){

    if(mouseX>=this.attrs.respondLeft && mouseX<=this.attrs.respondRight){
        this.attrs.endX=mouseX;
    }
    var context = canvas.getContext();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.attrs.startX,this.attrs.bottomY);
    context.lineTo(this.attrs.startX,this.attrs.midY);
    context.lineTo(this.attrs.endX,this.attrs.topY);
    canvas.fillStroke(this);
},
```

Since we want the hair to bend itself as the mouse moves over it,  we add a mousemove event handler for the stage.  When the mouse moves the mouseX position is updated.  When the hair is redrawn, it will be bent to the mouseX.

```
stage.on('mousemove', function() {

    // set the endX where the hair will bend to
    mouseX=stage.getMousePosition().x;

    // redraw the layer
    layer.draw();

});
```

The working code below is a little more complicated because each hair stores its own info about how to draw itself and about its hit area.

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/ey38w/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:300px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var mouseX;

    var hair1=addHair(100,200,20,150);
    var hair2=addHair(120,200,20,150);
    var hair3=addHair(140,200,20,150);
    layer.draw();

    function addHair(x,y,width,height){
        var shape=new Kinetic.Shape({
            drawFunc: function(canvas){

                if(mouseX>=this.attrs.respondLeft && mouseX<=this.attrs.respondRight){
                    this.attrs.endX=mouseX;
                }
                var context = canvas.getContext();
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(this.attrs.startX,this.attrs.bottomY);
                context.lineTo(this.attrs.startX,this.attrs.midY);
                context.lineTo(this.attrs.endX,this.attrs.topY);
                canvas.fillStroke(this);
            },
            lineJoin: 'round',
            stroke: 'grey',
            strokeWidth: 12,
            respondWidth:width,
            respondLeft:x-width/2,
            respondRight:x+width/2,
            respondHeight:height,
            respondTop:y-100,
            topY:y-100,
            midY:y-50,
            bottomY:y,
            startX:x,
            endX:x
        });
        layer.add(shape);
        return(shape);
    }

    // "bend" when mouse is inside any hairs hit boundaries 
    stage.on('mousemove', function() {
        // set the endX where the hair will bend to
        mouseX=stage.getMousePosition().x;
        layer.draw();
    });


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Additional words of encouragement]**

This pattern will work for you.

Yes…even for your bezier curves.

But this is just a starting point that you must adjust for your own project.

For example, in your original code you went through these steps

- Listen for mousemove events and handle them (your moving function),
- Determine if the mouse position should affect your hairs,
- If so, recalculate the control+end points (your init function).
- Redraw the hairs (only now you know to just redraw the existing hairs--not create new ones),

So modify these code pieces into this pattern!

No, you can't just cut-and-paste.  You will have to modify, improve, adapt.

To start, get 1 Bezier hair working the way you like.

Then--not before, take this hint:

Instead of having a separate Kinetic Shape for each hair, create one Shape object and draw all you hairs in its drawFunc. This is more performant.  Also, then you can listen for mousemove on that one shape instead of the whole canvas. Again, more performant.

Above all—Learn!: (1)Experiment (2)Test, (3)Adapt, (4)Don't Give Up, (5)Repeat at#1.

Comment: how to avoid this then??can you give me a sample code or just the idea of it.I know I am asking for to much.But I am fairly new to kineticjs and its the first time i using some framework.

Comment: :thanyou,your logic is more simpler

Comment: :but with your code,whats happening is only the last hair is able to move,rest of the hairs stand still..
What we want is individual control of every hair,like the link without kinetic above,and also the performance is not that smooth either??

Comment: I just noticed that my fiddle pointed to previous code that did have a problem moving multiple hairs--sorry. (However, the code in my original answer was properly updated code).  I updated the fiddle link.  About performance: this sample is simplified to educate you, but you can fairly easily change it into more performant code.

Comment: yes,i noticed it.but when i coded with your pattern including bezier curve instead of rect,they were not moving

Comment: is there some different pattern for bezier curve

Comment: Nope.  This pattern will work for you (even Beziers) You just need to change the Bezier points based on the mouse position.  See words of encouragement added to my answer :)

Comment: i tried wat you said!!!but i will give that one more try!!!thanks for the answers..
and is  it possible to give transition to bezire curves for increasing  their heights?just a general question

Comment: Yes.  Since your beziers start vertically, just make the "Y" of the endpoint higher and your beziers will stretch higher.  If they deform too much for your taste, you might have to also adjust the "Y" of your control points higher also.

Comment: this is exactly what I was thinking..and probably some setInterval with 1/10th of a second will increase the y by some pixels,but wouldnt this cause the canvas to redraw and redraw it again and again,eventually ruining up the performance?

Comment: Yes, some performance hit.  If you need the hair to "grow" only on mousemove, you can change the control points inside drawFunc and you will get enough mousemove/redraws to make the hair grow.  If you want the hair to grow through animation not related to mousemove you could change the control points **outside drawFunc** and then use requestAnimationFrame to do the animation.  See this nice post on requestAnimationFrame: http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/  As always...why not try it out! ;)

Answer (score 0):

KineticJS now supports Spline tweening, which means that you can easily animate the points along a curve.  Check out this example:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-animated-clown-face/